# Excel VBA - Selecting a range of files to search through

Tags: file, excel, search, vba

I really hope someone can help me with this....

I have a macro at the moment that allows the user to input an 8 digit number and then the code searchs all .xls files in a specific folder until it finds that number. So far there are 61 files to search through and that number is getting bigger every day! My code works fine but it is a slow process and one that the user will be doing many times a day.

Desired outcome - the user will input a date, ie - 2013-10-28, which is the first part of a file name, then input a second date in the same format and then an 8 digit number. The macro will then open a preset folder, find the first file, open it and search for the 8 digit number. If the number is not found i want the macro to move to the next file in the folder until either the number is found or it reaches the second date defined folder at which point it will stop.

Worst case i'd like my existing macro to function the same but start with the most recently modified file and work backwards to cut down the running time.

This is what i have so far (vaCellvalue is the 8 digit number input by the user):-

```
Sub UKSearch()

Dim FSO As Object 'FileSystemObject
Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Dim Directory As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim varCellvalue As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
MsgBox ("This may take a few minutes")

'value to be searched
varCellvalue = Range("D13").Value

'Change the directory below as needed
Directory = "\\**********\shared$\******\*******\********\"
If Right(Directory, 1) <> "\" Then
   Directory = Directory & "\"
 End If

'Search for all files in the directory with an xls* file type.
FileName = Dir(Directory & "*.xls*")

'Opens, searches through and closes each file
Do While FileName <> ""
OpenFile = Directory & FileName
Workbooks.Open (OpenFile)

Workbooks(FileName).Activate

'Count through all the rows looking for the required number
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UK Scan Sheet").Activate
LastRow = Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row

intRowCount = LastRow

Range("B1").Select

For i = 1 To intRowCount
    'If the required number is found then select it and stop the search
   If ActiveCell.Value = varCellvalue Then
       GoTo Finish
       Else
   End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next i

Workbooks(FileName).Close
FileName = Dir
OpenFile = ""
Loop

Finish:

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub`
```

Comment: Is 8 digit number part of file name ?

Comment: No sorry i should have made that clearer - the 8 digit number is contained in one of the cells in one of the files - the macro searches through all the files until it hits the right cell and then stops

Comment: Perhaps importing historical data to a database would work? If you want this to scale out into the future you could capture as least the search info: Filename + values that are the target.

Comment: Hi rheitzman! I'm not sure how that would really help here? If you mean put all the data into one workbook that wouldn't help the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else out there who might one day ask this question here is the answer that i came up with in the end. Please be aware however as stated in my original question above, the dates involved here are file names - when the input box asks for a file creation date it is really asking the user for the first part of a file name that happens to always be a date.

```
Sub OpenByCreationDate()

Dim appShell As Object
Dim FileName As Variant
Dim FilePath As Variant
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFolderItem As Object
Dim TestDate As Variant
Dim IntCount As Variant

FolderPath = "\\cor-***-****\shared$\Common\Returns\**************\"
FileName = "*.xls*"

EnterDate:
TestDate = inputbox("Enter the file creation date below.")
  If Not IsDate(TestDate) Then
     MsgBox "The Date you entered is not valid." & vbCrLf _
            & "Please enter the date again."
     GoTo EnterDate
  End If

SearchValue = inputbox("Enter the consignment number below.")

IntCount = 0

Set appShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set oFolder = appShell.Namespace(FolderPath)

For Each oFolderItem In oFolder.Items
    If IntCount > 0 Then
    TestDate = Left(oFolderItem.Name, 10)
    Else
    End If
        If oFolderItem.Name Like TestDate & FileName Then

            Workbooks.Open oFolderItem.Path

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UK Scan Sheet").Activate
        LastRow = Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row

        intRowCount = LastRow

        Range("B1").Select

        For i = 1 To intRowCount
         'If the required number is found then select it and stop the search
         If ActiveCell.Value = SearchValue Then
            ActiveCell.Select
            MsgBox "Consignment number found."
            GoTo Finish
         Else
         End If
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Next i

    ActiveWorkbook.Close

       IntCount = IntCount + 1
            If IntCount = 10 Then
                MsgBox "Consignment number could not be found, please try a different date."
                Exit Sub
            Else
            End If

        End If
Next oFolderItem

Finish:

End Sub
```